# Definition of "secular" in the context of markets?

Tags: terminology, markets

When fund managers makes statements like this...

"... [many market] inefficiencies persist for years due to the long-term nature of *secular* and structural changes [...]"

... I assume that they are not referring to declining church-attendance.

So, if they aren't using "secular" in its normal sense, what do they mean by the term?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> In the finance industry, something
>   done on a secular basis is done on a
>   long-term basis, not a temporary or
>   cyclical one, with a time frame of
>   "10–50 years or more"

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_basis)

Comment: Extra credit: Given the definition according the wikipedia, isn't the quote in the question the very definition of circular logic? "Market inefficiencies persist for years due to the long term nature of *secular* and structural change..." essentially saying, "Market inefficiencies last for years due to the long term nature of *long term* and structural changes?"

Answer (score 1):

Secular means a long term.

A secular basis is something done on a long term basis while a secular trend is a long term trend.

http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Secular